# VBOs or another way?

Tags: c++, opengl

I've just finished my basic OpenGL model loader, and now I want to move over to VBOs instead of `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`. I read in an article that even VBOs are deprecated.

My question is: Are VBOs really deprecated and **is there a better way to draw objects in OpenGL?** Should I be using display lists perhaps?

Comment: Not to my best knowledge. I haven't done serious OpenGL in a few months but this would be surprising news to me. Can you provide a link to the article?

Comment: I would call display lists more deprecated than VBOs. As far as I know VBOs are the recommended way from GL 3.0 upwards and glBegin/End are deprecated. Could you provide any information (a link?) on the article you read?

Comment: @Nobody Here's the article: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO_-_just_examples

Comment: I am pretty sure that the Deprecationwarning on top of the page does not mean the VBOs but something like the clientside state functions or so on.

Comment: @JamWaffles I think the deprecation notice in this article is more due to the use of deprecated fixed-function attributes (like `glVertexPointer`,...) instead of custom shader attributes (using `glVertexAttribPointer`) or maybe the not-use of VAOs. But the VBOs themselves are DEFINITELY not deprecated, as they are the only non-dperecated way for drawing objects.

Comment: glBegin -> multiple calls per vertex. Display lists -> One call per object, but nonhomogeneous data so hard to get optimized. VBOs -> One call per object, homogeneous data so easily optimized. Use VBOs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vertex Buffer Objects are not deprecated. In fact, I believe they are the *only* (non-deprecated) way to render in OpenGL 3.0 and above.

See the OpenGL page on [Vertex Buffer Object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object).

> **Legacy Note**: Versions of OpenGL prior to 3.0 allowed the use of
>   client-side data for vertex rendering, but GL 3.0 deprecated this.
>   Core GL 3.1 and greater forbid client-side vertex data, so VBOs are
>   the only means for rendering.